# Gatsby 3.0 broken on MacOS after recent upgrade

Tags: macos, gatsby

My Gatsby apps started breaking and also the CLI started to not work after the recent Gatsby update to version 3.0. Anyone else sees this or knows how to fix this?

```
MacBook-Air:gatsby-site $ gatsby 

 ERROR 

Usage: gatsby <command> [options]

Commands:
  gatsby develop                      Start development server. Watches files, rebuilds, and hot reloads if something changes
  gatsby build                        Build a Gatsby project.
  gatsby serve                        Serve previously built Gatsby site.
  gatsby info                         Get environment information for debugging and issue reporting
  gatsby clean                        Wipe the local gatsby environment including built assets and cache
  gatsby repl                         Get a node repl with context of Gatsby environment, see (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-repl/)
  gatsby recipes [recipe]             [EXPERIMENTAL] Run a recipe
  gatsby plugin <cmd> [plugins...]    Useful commands relating to Gatsby plugins
  gatsby new [rootPath] [starter]     Create new Gatsby project.
  gatsby telemetry                    Enable or disable Gatsby anonymous analytics collection.
  gatsby options [cmd] [key] [value]  View or set your gatsby-cli configuration settings.

Options:
  --verbose                Turn on verbose output                                                                                                                               [boolean] [default: false]
  --no-color, --no-colors  Turn off the color in output                                                                                                                         [boolean] [default: false]
  --json                   Turn on the JSON logger                                                                                                                              [boolean] [default: false]
  -h, --help               Show help                                                                                                                                                             [boolean]
  -v, --version            Show the version of the Gatsby CLI and the Gatsby package in the current project                                                                                      [boolean]


 ERROR 

There was an error


 ERROR 

Pass --help to see all available commands and options.


MacBook-Air:gatsby-site $ gatsby -v
Gatsby CLI version: 3.0.0
MacBook-Air:gatsby-site $
```

Comment: What happens when you type a proper command like 'gatsby develop'?

Comment: Extending @SimonCooper question, which I'm also interested. What happens when run `gatsby info`?

Comment: That seems to be fine without throwing errors. It gave me a bunch of system, binaries, browsers, npmpackages info